# Ubuntu server 20.04 - time format 24 hours on shell with date command

Tags: 20.04, format, time

I've installed Ubuntu server 20.04, and I can't find a way to display the time format to 24 hours when I use the command 'date' in the shell.
I check the locale information with an Ubuntu server 18.04 and all seems the same, but on 18.04 i have the date in 24 hours format

```
Mon May 11 22:41:08 CEST 2020
```

while in 20.04 is "different" and in 12 hours format

```
Mon 11 May 2020 10:41:40 PM CEST
```

The following are the result of the locale command
Ubuntu 18.04

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Ubuntu 20.04

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

This is the result of command localectl

Ubuntu 18.04

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: it
       X11 Model: pc105
```

Ubuntu 20.04

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: it
       X11 Model: pc105
```

I don't know where to look at to change the time in 24 Hours format like in Ubuntu 18.04.
Can someone give me some help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to change `LC_TIME` variable to locale that uses desired time formatting. `en_GB` uses 24h clock for example. You can set it system-wide using `localectl`:

```
localectl set-locale LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

Then, you have to relogin to see changes.

Alternatively, you can customize date and time formatting in locale definition file `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US`. You will find date and time formatting in the following section:

```
% Appropriate date and time representation (%c)
d_t_fmt "%a %d %b %Y %r %Z"
%
% Appropriate date representation (%x)
d_fmt   "%m//%d//%Y"
%
% Appropriate time representation (%X)
t_fmt   "%r"
%
% Appropriate AM/PM time representation (%r)
t_fmt_ampm "%I:%M:%S %p"
%
% Appropriate date and time representation for date(1)
date_fmt "%a %d %b %Y %r %Z"
```

In this case, to get 24h clock, you have to replace `%r` to `%T` and run `locale-gen` to regenerate locales.

Comment: Hi Mateusz, thank you for your answer.
I used the command `localectl set-locale LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8` and now the date is correct, but it changed all the `LC_*` settings to `"C.UTF-8"` I don't know if this may cause some problems.
The strange thing is that i didn't had to change anything on the previous Ubuntu versions to have the date displayed in 24-hours format.

Comment: Hi, `C` is default locale when no locale is set, and it should not cause any problems. I suppose that now you see `C` value because you do not have any locale set to main `LANG` variable. To check your current configuration see file `/etc/default/locale`. If you want, you can set `LANG` by running `localectl set-locale en_US.UTF-8` or by manually editing config file.

Comment: 24-hour clock in en_US locale was a bug in glibc locale definition and has been corrected in [this commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=7395f3a0efad9fc51bb54fa383ef6524702e0c49). So, the change was intentional.

Comment: Thank you, now it make sense. Tomorrow when i get back to work i will try to set `LANG`, but I would like to understand correctly what I'm doing. The `LANG` variable at the beginning was set to `en_US.UTF-8`, with the command `localectl set-locale LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8` only the variable `LC_TIME` had to change, but all the variables `LC_TIME` included, changed to `C.UTF-8`. Shouldn't just change only the `LC_TIME` variable and leave the others variables unchanged ?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. `localectl` should have just add definition for `LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8` in `/etc/default/locale`. I tested this before I posted my answer, and it worked as expected.
It looks like you have lost somehow your original `LANG` value, but unfortunately I do not know why. This would explain that all `LC_*` changed its value. Normally all `LC_*` variables are not explicitly defined. You define one of them when you want to override some locale setting. When some `LC_` variable is not defined the `locale` command will show it with value inherited from `LANG`.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, with the command `locale -a` I have a list of all the avialable locale and there wasn't the `it_IT.utf8` so i use the command `locale-get it_IT.utf8` to generate the locale and then rebooted. Now I have all the locale setting correctly, all the `LC_*` are set to `en_US.UTF-8` except `LC_TIME` that is set to `it_IT.utf8`. I didn't like it because I get 24-hours format but also the date is translate in Italian. I set the `LC_TIME` to `C.UTF-8` and now all the locale parameters are set correctly and the format for date/time is correct. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Rather than replacing all the `%r`s with `%T`s you can also adjust the definition of `%r` itself, a few lines lower down in the same file.  For instance, I was able to change `%I` to `%H`  just once, in the line below the comment "Appropriate date representation (%r)", and saw a change to 24 hour time in all contexts I've tried so far

Comment: The other answer works.  I don't know why the 24-hours format has to have anything to do with "Great Britain" or "United States".

Answer (score 4):

To get `date` to display 24-hour time you need to set `LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"`.

On Ubuntu 22.04 `sudo localectl set-locale LC_TIME=C.UTF-8` only updates `/etc/locale.conf`, which doesn't seem to have any effect on the output of `date`, even after logging out and logging back in. Rebooting doesn't affect the output of `date` either.

However, changing the setting in `/etc/default/locale` does change the output of `date` so it displays 24 hour time.

So add this line to `/etc/default/locale`:

```
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
```

Comment: This is still an issue on 22.04.  I only applied the `/etc/default/locale` change and it fixed my particular issue: the change to the default behaviour of `date` broke all of my scripts, many of which predate notions of locale.

Comment: I just learned that `update-locale 'LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"'` works on 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

The answers suggesting that adding `LC_TIME=C.UTF-8` to the environment will fix the issue, did not do the trick as written for me.

What *did* make it work, was to edit `/etc/default/locale` to read:

> ```sh
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
> LC_ALL=
> LC_TIME=C.UTF-8
> ```

With this:

- `LANG` specifies the default for any `LC_*` variable that isn't set explicitly (excluding `LC_ALL`);
- `LC_ALL` is set empty to prevent it from overruling any individual `LC_*` setting;
- `LC_TIME`, as mentioned before, is set to a value that will allow `date` to produce time values using a 24-hour format;

As you now might guess, adding `LC_TIME=C.UTF-8` alone wasn't sufficient, because on my system - a fresh Ubuntu `22.04` install - `LC_ALL` was also set (to `en_US.UTF-8`) and that prevented any `LC_*` customization to take hold.

The output of the `locale` command line tool helps to get this clear; Whatever `LANG` and `LC_*` environment variables are set, it will reveal the currently effective locale categories:

- `LC_ALL` value overrules everything:

  ```bash
  LANG=whatever  LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8  LC_TIME=C.UTF-8  locale
  ```

  > ```sh
  > LANG=whatever
  > LANGUAGE=
  > LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
  >
  > LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
  >
  > LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
  > ```
- `LANG` provides default value for any unset `LC_*` category:

  ```bash
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8  LC_ALL=  LC_TIME=C.UTF-8  locale
  ```

  > ```sh
  > LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  > LANGUAGE=
  > LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
  >
  > LC_TIME=C.UTF-8
  >
  > LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
  > LC_ALL=
  > ```
- There is a default (`POSIX`) even when `LANG` isn't set:

  ```bash
  LANG=  LC_ALL=  LC_TIME=C.UTF-8  locale
  ```

  > ```sh
  > LANG=
  > LANGUAGE=
  > LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
  > LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
  >
  > LC_TIME=C.UTF-8
  >
  > LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
  > LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
  > LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
  > LC_PAPER="POSIX"
  > LC_NAME="POSIX"
  > LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
  > LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
  > LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
  > LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
  > LC_ALL=
  > ```

Seeing what environment variables are set for you:

```bash
env | egrep '^(LANG|LC_)'
```

... should now help to make sense of what `locale` reports as the currently effective locale categories;

---

On said fresh Ubuntu `22.04` install, `env | egrep '^(LANG|LC_)'` reported:

> ```sh
> LANG=C.UTF-8
> LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
> ```

And yet, `etc/default/locale` only contained:

> ```sh
> LANG=C.UTF-8
> ```

I have yet to find an origin for that `LC_ALL` default, but it does explain why only adding `LC_CTIME=C.UTF-8` did not have any effect, *and* why `C.UTF-8` wasn't the default category value anyway, as `LANG=C.UTF-8` suggested.

---

More detailed output of `locale` *also* helps to understand the observed behavioral differences between Ubuntu `22.04` and earlier;

To reveal the exact format string that `date` will use by default, use:

```bash
locale date_fmt
```

- Ubuntu `22.04`:

  | command | output |
  | --- | --- |
  | `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 locale date_fmt` | `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y` |
  | `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 locale date_fmt` | `%a %b %e %r %Z %Y` |
- Ubuntu `18.04`:

  | command | output |
  | --- | --- |
  | `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 locale date_fmt` | `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y` |
  | `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 locale date_fmt` | `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y` |

This reveals that it is due to differences of the `en_US.UTF-8` locale configurations themselves between these systems.

The `LANG` and `LC_ALL` environment variables had, in fact, the exact same values;

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for finding an `LC_ALL` environment variable set to a value counteracting any settings you might make in `/etc/default/locale`, could be the fact that on Ubuntu, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf`, by default, there's an `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*` directive, causing any locally set `LC_ALL` value to be happily accepted when an `ssh` client passes it along to another machine.

This turned out to be the ultimate cause for me encountering an `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF8` on a machine that was trying to be `C.UTF8` only - and the reason [I initialy resorted to counteracting it by resetting `LC_ALL` to the empty string in `/etc/default/locale`](/a/1500471/959040);

The final solution was commenting out the offending directive from `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf`, and setting `/etc/default/locale` to just `LANG=C.UTF-8`.